# Write sentences ϕ in the language of groups

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Don't know where and how to start.

Write sentences ϕ in the language of groups, i.e, the language with

• binary function symbol ·, interpreted as multiplication,

• unary function symbol −1, interpreted as inversion,

• and constant symbol e, which is interpreted as the identity element,

1. G entails ϕ if and only if G is isomorphic to the symmetric group on three
   letters.
2. G entails ϕ if and only if G is abelian; if and only if G is nonabelian.
   Draw the parsing trees for each formula, underline all subformulas
   and indicate their free variables.
3. G entails ϕ if and only if G has an element of order n; if and only if every
   element of G has order n.
4. G entails ϕ if and only if G has a nontrivial central element; if and only if
   G has trivial center.

Comment: Really no idea ? The task is straightforward, provided that you have learned the syntax of predicate logic.

Comment: so for an abelian group I don't have to write out the sentences for inverse, identity elements, associativity etc.? Just commutativity?

Comment: If so, the sentence $\phi$ must be formed with the conjunction of the [Group axiom](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Group_Axioms) **plus** the axiom specifiying commutativity.

Comment: so for G an abelian group i write:   a sentence for identity element expression, a sentence for inverse element expression, a sentence for associativity and senctence for commutativity. Right? and for non-abelian all the sentences hold except for non-commutativity, which is a negation of commutativity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

For each bullett, we have to write a sentence $\phi$ such that :

> $G \vDash \phi \text { iff } G \text { is a Group with the specified propertry }$.

We can start writing a single sentence $\text {Grax}$ specifying the [Group axioms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Group_Axioms) :

> $\text {Grax} :=  [∀a, b, c (a \circ (b \circ c) = (a \circ b) \circ c)] \land [ ∃e∀a (e \circ a = a) \land (a \circ e = a)] \land [ ∃e ∀a ∃b (a \circ b = e) \land (b \circ 
> a=e)]$.

Having done this, we can consider e.g. the *abelian* case, writing the formula specifying *Commutativity* :

> $\text {Comm} := ∀a∀b(a \circ b = b \circ a)$.

Thus, a group $G$ is *abelian* iff :

> > $G \vDash \text {Grax} \land \text {Comm}$.

Comment: and how would you write the last bullet point?